# Font scaling in 2d context

Tags: qt, qml

So far I have handles my Text objects like this:

```
FontLoader
{
    id: roboFont;
    source: "qrc:/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf";
}
```

...

Example usage, not MWE:

```
Text
{
    id: theTitle;
    font.pointSize: fontSizeTitle * scale;
    color: col;
    font.family: roboFont.name;
    y: yOffsetTitle * scale;
    font.letterSpacing: fontSpacingTitle * scale;
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
}
```

I could easily set the font style and scale its size. At the moment I need to use the same mechanism in `Canvas` with 2d context. The problem there is that the font is defined differently, like this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.font = "bold 17px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("Qt Quick", 40, 70);
```

Sources: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-example.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#font-prop

Is there any way I can still set the font style to the one I have in resources and scale it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
ctx.font = '%1pt %2'.arg(fontSizeTitle * scale).arg(roboFont.name);
```

If the name of the font contains spaces, you will also have to quote it:

```
ctx.font = '%1pt "%2"'.arg(fontSizeTitle * scale).arg(roboFont.name);
```

---

For the `letterSpacing`, it does not look like it is possible in a [`Context2D`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#font-prop):

> A subset of the w3C 2d context standard for font is supported:
>
> - font-style (optional): normal | italic | oblique
> - font-variant (optional): normal | small-caps
> - font-weight (optional): normal | bold | 0 ... 99
> - font-size: Npx | Npt (where N is a positive number)
> - font-family: See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family

If really needed, there is still the option to do it manually.